Why is the return type correct if I'm not returning the Mock?
I have this trait which I mix in as needed in my test suites:
trait ValidationMock {

  def createValidationMock(result: Either[Error, Unit] = Right(())): Validation = {
    val validationMock = mock[Validation]

    validationMock.validateEligibility(any[Request], any[String])(any[Context]) returns result
  }
}

This compiles and test run successfully when instantiating this mock in the tests as:
val validationMock = createValidationMock()
But why does it work, if the validationMock mock created in the createValidationMock method is not being returned in the method?

Uhm I have never used any mocking library for a lot of reasons. But I gues the whole weird macro / reflection based DSL does end up returning the mocked class at the end.

Never seen this syntax mock.method(...) returns value. I'd rather go with the traditional when(mock.method(...)).thenReturn(value) and avoid any more magic.

returns "only" adds extension methods (instead of wrapping with when). The worst magic was already there: taking object.call(args) AST and rewriting it to something completely different, either by macros (Scala) or some bytecode manipulation library (Java).


But why does it work, if the validationMock mock created in the createValidationMock method is not being returned in the method?

Because it is:

mockAction.returns returns ReturnAction[mockAction.type] (see code)
then apply returns ScalaOngoingStubbing[mockAction.type] (see code)
then implicit conversion extracts mock out of that value (see code) - pay attention that [T] in implicit conversion is the mock-type not the mocked call's result type

So all of that is basically
ScalaOngoingStubbing.toMock[Validation](
  new StubbingOps(
    validationMock.validateEligibility(any[Request], any[String])(any[Context])
  ) // this wrapper is probably erased by the macros
    .returns // ReturnAction[Either[Error, Unit]]
    .apply(result) // ScalaOngoingStubbing[Either[Error, Unit]]
) // Validation

I wouldn't be surprised if toMock wasn't just extraction + some asInstanceOf on steroids.
